# What is a better way to rewrite this JSON to jQuery data()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, function

For some reason I have this huge brain fart today. >.<

I have a JSON data that I am attaching to using jQuery .data() that looks like this:

```
$.getJSON("names.php", function(data) {
    //generate html string and append to DOM
    $.each(data, function(i,item) {
        var strHtml;
        strHtml += '<img src="' +item.PIC + '.jpg" id="' + item.ID  + '" />';
    })
    $('body').html(strHtml);

    //attach data to image ID
    $.each(data, function(i,item) {
        $('#' + item.ID).data(item.ID, {
            NAME: item.NAME,
            PHONE: item.PHONE,
            EMAIL: item.EMAIL,
            ADDRESS: item.ADDRESS,
            ...
            ...
            ...
        });
    }
}
```

This works fine; however, it looks a little ugly and I am trying to clean it up a little mainly on this part:

```
    $.each(data, function(i,item) {
        $('#' + item.ID).data(item.ID, {
            NAME: item.NAME,
            PHONE: item.PHONE,
            EMAIL: item.EMAIL,
            ADDRESS: item.ADDRESS,
            ...
            ...
            ...
        });
    }
```

I am adding an array of object to the key value.
Example from http://api.jquery.com/data/
$('body').data('bar', { myType: 'test', count: 40 });

Here is my attempt to rewrite it:

```
$.each(data, function(i,item) {
    $('#' + item.ID).data(item.ID, function(){
        $.each(item) {
            return i + ':' item[i];
        }
    })
}
```

Is there a cleaner way to write this?
I've also tried $('#' + item.ID).data(item.ID, JSON.stringify(data));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want the full item added, with all it's properties, you can just do this:

```
$.each(data, function(i,item) {
    $('#' + item.ID).data(item.ID, item);
});
```

[`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) takes any value, including an object, so you might as well use the original.  Also, it's more likely that you want this:

```
$.each(data, function(i, item) {
    $('#' + item.ID).data("someKey", item);
});
```

Then you can use a consistent `.data("someKey")` to get the data back out as well, rather than using the element's own `.id` as the data key as well.

Comment: This is what I need .data( key, obj ) and I was only thinking .data( key, value ) only.

Comment: @nolabel - you should be all set with that approach, much simpler too :)

Comment: Thanks Nick! Each key have to be unique in my case b/c I need to call the data in relation to it's ID.

Comment: @nolabel - it won't be the only data thing like this on that element?

Comment: @Nick - You are correct. There will be quite a few others data thing like this element. Is there a better approach for this? The reason why I used this approach is to avoid another SQL trip for the same information.

Comment: @nolabel - You can use the element's `.id` property since it's the same, or `.data("someKey").ID`, but I don't think you need to have the key change each time...at least not that I can imagine.

Comment: @Nick - let me see if I can get this straight.

So instead of getting this way:

$('#bgate').data('bgate');
$('#sjob').data('sjob');

I can set it like this:
$('#bgate').data('globalKey', [data.object]);
$('#sjob').data('globalKey', [data.object]);

Then I can get the data like this:
$('#bgate').data('globalKey');
$('#sjob').data('globalKey');

Sorry, I had to write this all out to understand.

Comment: @nolabel - yup, that same key can be used for each.

Answer (score 1):

You can just do:

```
$('#' + item.ID).data(item.ID, item);
```

You'll still be able to access the values as expected:

```
$('#' + someId).data(someId).NAME;
```

By the way, JSON.stringify isn't a good idea because in order to read the values back again, you'll have to convert it back from a string into an object.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I will keep JSON.stringify in mind in regards to the need to convert them back.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

`$('#' + item.ID).data("info", item);`